# adding annotations to file outside workspace

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I need to show annotations on files outside of Workspace.

I am able to show annotations on files present in Worspace
When i try to do the same for files outside the Workspace I need to create resource and ifile object. How do i achieve the same?
How do i read contents of file outside workspace since i am unable to create a ifile object.

Here is what i am doing right now:

```
IEditorPart editor =(IEditorPart) wins[i].getPartService().getActivePart()
IEditorInput input = editor.getEditorInput();
IPath path = ((FileEditorInput)input).getPath();
IFile file= workspace.getRoot().getFileForLocation(path);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case you don't know, files and projects don't have to the under the workspace's folder on the file system to be *in* the workspace.

---

Maybe you can surreptitiously add a [hidden project](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/resources/IProject.html) to the workspace and [link](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/resources/IProject.html) the file as a resource in it. I don't think that an external file converted to an internal file loses any behaviors. But, it could gain more than you want. One that I can think of is that source control plugins might then detect it.

Or, you could point out to the user that there are advantages to adding the file to the workspace and let them make the choice. You might be able to show a dialog asking which new or existing project/folder to add it to. Of course, if they decline then you should remember and not ask again about that external file.

**UPDATE:**

`FileStoreEditorInput` represents a file that is not part of the current workspace. To listen for external files being opened, subscribe with an IPartListener2 on each window.

```
public class Activator extends AbstractUIPlugin implements IStartup {

    @Override
    public void earlyStartup() {
        final PartListener partListener = new PartListener();
        for (final IWorkbenchWindow window : getWorkbench().getWorkbenchWindows()) {
            window.getPartService().addPartListener(partListener);
        }
        getWorkbench().addWindowListener(new IWindowListener() {

            @Override
            public void windowOpened(IWorkbenchWindow window) {
                window.getPartService().addPartListener(partListener);
            }

        });
    }

    private class PartListener implements IPartListener2 {
        @Override
        public void partOpened(final IWorkbenchPartReference partRef) {
            if (partRef.getPart(false) instanceof EditorPart) {
                final EditorPart editor = (EditorPart) partRef.getPart(false);
                if (editor.getEditorInput() instanceof FileStoreEditorInput) {
                    final FileStoreEditorInput input = (FileStoreEditorInput) editor.getEditorInput();
                    System.out.println(input.getURI());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi to add a hidden project i need to put code when a file open action takes place.Is there a file open listener or something similar where i can put this code?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot annotation files outside of workspace. An IFile is only defined for workspace files.